# Allow root access without passwd

Tags: password, root, settings, passwd

Have a VirtualBox Ubuntu guest (14.04) used for the sake of testing only.
The *root* user has its own password, so I can login as root in a separate terminal (`su -`), or directly from a login session (eg after Ctrl-Alt-F4).

```
$ su -
Password: <current root password>
# echo Works!
```

Since it is a VB testing system, and the *root* user does not need any security, I want to be able to `su -` or `login` as root quickly, i.e. without *root* having a password.

So, tried as *root*

```
# passwd -d root
```

to remove the *root* password - it seems to work according to /etc/shadow (`::`)

```
root::16304:0:99999:7:::
```

but when trying to `su -`, it asks for a password, I just press *enter* (no password)

```
$ su -
Password: 
su: Authentication failure
```

but it doesn't *su*.

There has to be a setting somewhere to allow *root* to login/su without password.
Where would that be?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Warning; not tested because I think it's not such a great idea, even for a VM (bad habits are difficult to remove...).

I think this is a PAM thing (PAM=[pluggable authentication modules](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-pam-to-configure-authentication-on-an-ubuntu-12-04-vps)).

In `/etc/pam.d` there are all the PAM configuration files that tell the system how to do the authentication of users. Now, the module that check for the passwords "unix style" is `pam_unix.so`, in which man page you can find among the options:

> ```
>   nullok
>        The default action of this module is to not permit the user access
>        to a service if their official password is blank. The nullok
>        argument overrides this default and allows any user with a blank
>        password to access the service.
>
>    nullok_secure
>        The default action of this module is to not permit the user access
>        to a service if their official password is blank. The nullok_secure
>        argument overrides this default and allows any user with a blank
>        password to access the service as long as the value of PAM_TTY is
>        set to one of the values found in /etc/securetty.
> ```

So I suspect is a matter of finding all the occurences of `pam_unix.so` in the files above, and add the option `nullok` (or change the `nullok_secure` to `nullok`) to the entries.

According [to this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/50501/how-to-remove-root-password-on-debian) the file should be `/etc/pam.d/common-auth` --- but I am not sure about this because in Ubuntu the VC are in the `/etc/securetty` list so the null password for root should work from there (although not from a terminal emulator), and the SO states it doesn't work.

So a bit of experimentation will be needed ;-).

Comment: I agree that this is a bad idea.....

Comment: Indeed it's in `/etc/pam.d/common-auth`, line with `pam_unix.so`, change `nullok_secure` to `nullok` (and in any other required *auth*  files). Thanks for considering privileged users as adults, and providing a solution while warning the less experienced readers.

Answer (score 6):

try

```
sudo -s
```

It will ask your password to login in as root.

then use `passwd` to change the root password.

if you are not in sudo user

type

```
sudo visudo
```

add this line in the last

```
<username> ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL
```

then <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> to exit then ,<kbd>y</kbd> to save the changes

then try again `sudo -s` it will login  to **root without asking password**

Comment: Where did you see *sudo* in the question?